# how to execute the tasks from custom gradle plugin

Tags: gradle

Background:-

I have created a gradle plugin say XXX, which has

1)***a groovy class*** in a package which ***implements Plugin interface*** of org.gradle.api.plugin, and in overridden apply method i have written a functionality related to git,

2)In build.gradle of the plugin XXX I have another ***task*** as ***confluence*** which is implemeted with the use of plugin "com.github.qwazer.markdown-confluence"

```
XXX Plugin
    |_______ com.gradle.plugin.gitFunctionality
    |                       |________________ gitFunctionality(groovy class)
    |_______ build.gradle
```

build.gradle of the XXX plugin

```
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        "gradle-plugin-XXX" {
            id = "com.gradle.plugin.gitFunctionality"
            implementationClass = "com.gradle.plugin.gitFunctionality.ReportPlugin"
        }
    }
}
.
.
.
.
confluence {

    //upload page to confluence
.
.
}
```

Now I can test the plugin implementation locally with the help of publishToMavenLocal of maven.publish plugin, I have imported the plugin in one of the project say 'ABCD' from local maven

Questions

1) when I try to run the command `./gradlew build publishToMavenLocal` it runs only 1st that is git functionality and not the confluence Why?? I expected to run both gitFunctionality written in reportPlugin plus confluence task, but I can see the output printed for git

2)After importing the plugin in project ABCD if I want to execute these two task/plugin as last task for project ABCD what do I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can change task execution order using dependsOn, finalizedBy and some other features.

For example you can execute necessary tasks after run gradle build:

```
void apply(Project project) {

        //.. some code

        project.tasks.getByName('build').finalizedBy(
            project.tasks.getByName('gitFunctionality'),
            project.tasks.getByName('publishToMavenLocal')
        )
    }
```